# Pep 8 Conflict, Imports exceed 72 characters

Tags: python, import, pep8

What is / is there a best practice around long import statements in Python? Pep 8 allows 72-99 character long lines, but I find that I often exceed this limit which is a shame when I've made an effort to format the rest of my code.

> Some teams strongly prefer a longer line length. For code maintained
> exclusively or primarily by a team that can reach agreement on this
> issue, it is okay to increase the line length limit up to 99
> characters, provided that comments and docstrings are still wrapped at
> 72 characters.

Source: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Now of course, you can just import an entire package. i.e. `import numpy as np`, however I typically want to shorten my imports as much as possible to avoid reduce load times.

Comment: Unless you are using Java naming conventions (`CookieFactoryInterfaceFactoryMaker`) I don't see a reasonable use case for you to have such a long import statement/module names. Can you give an example?

Comment: "Now of course, you can just import an entire package. i.e. import numpy as np, however I typically want to shorten my imports as much as possible to avoid reduce load times." Wait, *what*? What do you think you are doing that reduces load times?

Comment: @DeepSpace, sure, see a below example:
from samplecode_server.backendstats.probabilistic_serializers import MultidimensionalSerializer, ProbabilisticSerializer

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, maybe there's a gap in my knowledge. Doesn't importing a library into your codebase add to the execution time? And isn't something like import numpy more expensive than from numpy.linalg import norm?

Comment: @CroissantEngineer no. It isn't. You can never import *just part* of a module, you always import the entire thing. The only thing that changes is what is placed in the current namepace. I.e., both `import my_module` and  `from my_module import SomeClass` *executes the entirety of `my_module.py`. The only difference is that the module object `my_module` is added to the namespace, in the other, it is effectively equivalent to `import my_module; MyClass = my_module.MyClass; del my_module`. You don't save anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can often avoid exceeding the the limit by putting parentheses around expressions. If there are parentheses you can break the expression inside them up over as many lines as you want. The other less-desirable way is to end a line with a backslash character which causes the newline following it to be ignored.

This is explained in the [Maximum Line Length](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) section of PEP 8.

Comment: I guess that Pep 328 supports what you're proposing. I've never seen a multi line import statement but there's a first time for everything I guess...

Comment: PEP 8 doesn't specifically mention `import`s, probably because parentheses work on them, too — and have since Python 2.4. You don't see it much because most code just imports the module and then prefixes its name to all references to stuff in it, like `tkinter.Frame` — which is supposedly a best practice i.e. "Explicit is better than implicit" in PEP 20. To reduce the amount of typing, you'll often see the module name bound to a short prefix such as `import tkinter as tk` . Another popular scheme is to just have multiple `import` statements from the same module.

Comment: P.S. BTW, I personally use a limit of 90 characters for code and 80 for comments.